# How to get all the container details running in an overlay network from swarm node

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-container

We need to call docker api programmatically. But /container/json api call only list container on that particular node but we want list of all the container across various docker nodes from swarm node.

Answer (score 0):

In Swarm terminology, you need to list the tasks (i.e containers). The api for listing all tasks can be found here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.27/#tag/Task

Comment: In container/json api we get a field called "status":  "Up 18 minutes (healthy)". Same kind of information we are not getting in task api (basically we need health status of container as well).

Comment: @ashish You can find this info under `Status` in the json response.

Comment: Status in task json response only talk about various states like running, failed, starting etc but it doesn't tell whether container is healthy or unhealthy.